# what the meaning of slim.metrics.streaming_sparse_average_precision_at_k?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tf-slim

This function refer to tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_sparse_average_precision_at_k,and the explanation in source code is follow,any one can explain it by giving some simply example? And I wonder whether this metric is same as the average precision calculation used in PASCAL VOC 2012 challenge.Thanks a lot.

```
   def sparse_average_precision_at_k(labels,
                                  predictions,
                                  k,
                                  weights=None,
                                  metrics_collections=None,
                                  updates_collections=None,
                                  name=None):
  """Computes average precision@k of predictions with respect to sparse labels.

  `sparse_average_precision_at_k` creates two local variables,
  `average_precision_at_<k>/total` and `average_precision_at_<k>/max`, that
  are used to compute the frequency. This frequency is ultimately returned as
  `average_precision_at_<k>`: an idempotent operation that simply divides
  `average_precision_at_<k>/total` by `average_precision_at_<k>/max`.

  For estimation of the metric over a stream of data, the function creates an
  `update_op` operation that updates these variables and returns the
  `precision_at_<k>`. Internally, a `top_k` operation computes a `Tensor`
  indicating the top `k` `predictions`. Set operations applied to `top_k` and
  `labels` calculate the true positives and false positives weighted by
  `weights`. Then `update_op` increments `true_positive_at_<k>` and
  `false_positive_at_<k>` using these values.

  If `weights` is `None`, weights default to 1. Use weights of 0 to mask values.

  Args:
    labels: `int64` `Tensor` or `SparseTensor` with shape
      [D1, ... DN, num_labels] or [D1, ... DN], where the latter implies
      num_labels=1. N >= 1 and num_labels is the number of target classes for
      the associated prediction. Commonly, N=1 and `labels` has shape
      [batch_size, num_labels]. [D1, ... DN] must match `predictions`. Values
      should be in range [0, num_classes), where num_classes is the last
      dimension of `predictions`. Values outside this range are ignored.
    predictions: Float `Tensor` with shape [D1, ... DN, num_classes] where
      N >= 1. Commonly, N=1 and `predictions` has shape
      [batch size, num_classes]. The final dimension contains the logit values
      for each class. [D1, ... DN] must match `labels`.
    k: Integer, k for @k metric. This will calculate an average precision for
      range `[1,k]`, as documented above.
    weights: `Tensor` whose rank is either 0, or n-1, where n is the rank of
      `labels`. If the latter, it must be broadcastable to `labels` (i.e., all
      dimensions must be either `1`, or the same as the corresponding `labels`
      dimension).
    metrics_collections: An optional list of collections that values should
      be added to.
    updates_collections: An optional list of collections that updates should
      be added to.
    name: Name of new update operation, and namespace for other dependent ops.

  Returns:
    mean_average_precision: Scalar `float64` `Tensor` with the mean average
      precision values.
    update: `Operation` that increments variables appropriately, and whose
      value matches `metric`.

  Raises:
    ValueError: if k is invalid.
  """
```